# Python: Summarize values from CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV-file which looks like this:

```
a,date,b
,2020-10-26 09:06:07,
,2020-10-26 16:15:20,
,2020-10-27 08:04:54,
,2020-10-28 22:09:16,
```

My question is:

Can I summarize my CSV so that it looks like this? (in a new CSV):

```
date, count
2020-10-26,2
2020-10-27,1
2020-10-28,1
```

So that every row which has data from the same day is summarized.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, the pandas library or the csv module seem like good candidates. Please provide a [mcve] so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished quite simply using the following logic, with either **core Python**, or **`pandas`** - whichever suits you best.

- Read the source CSV file.
- Count the occurrences of each date.
- Write the counts to a new CSV file.

---

#### Using only core Python

```
counts = {}

# Open source CSV and extract only dates.
with open('dates.csv')as f:
    dates = [i.strip().split(',')[1].split(' ')[0] for i in f][1:]
    
# Count date occurrences.
for i in dates:
    counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1
    
# Write the output to a new CSV file.
with open('dates_out.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('date,count\n')
    for k, v in counts.items():
        f.write(f'{k},{v}\n')
```

---

#### Using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the source CSV into a DataFrame.
df = pd.read_csv('dates.csv')

# Convert the `date` column to a `datetime` object and return the `date` part only.
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date

# Count occurrences and store the results to a new CSV file.
(df['date']
 .value_counts()
 .sort_index()
 .reset_index()
 .rename(columns={'index': 'date', 'date': 'count'})
 .to_csv('dates_out.csv', index=False))
```

---

#### Output

```
$ cat dates_out.csv 
date,count
2020-10-26,2
2020-10-27,1
2020-10-28,1
```

---

#### Source input file

For completeness, here are the contents of my testing source file, `dates.csv`.

```
col1,date,col3
a,2020-10-26 09:06:07,b
a,2020-10-26 16:15:20,b
a,2020-10-27 08:04:54,b
a,2020-10-28 22:09:16,b
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like the below ('zz.txt' is your data)

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(int)
with open('zz.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()][1:]
    for line in lines:
        data[line[1:line.find(' ')]] += 1
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'2020-10-26': 2, '2020-10-27': 1, '2020-10-28': 1})
```